# Clips subviews does not work with auto layouts constraint

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have `UIView` with auto layout constraint. My view contains subview. I have height constraint that I attached to my view controller as a property.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *headerViewHeightLayoutConstraint;
```

In view did load I set:

```
 [[self headerViewHeightLayoutConstraint] setConstant:0.0f];
```

But I still see subviews. So I check Clip subviews in storyboard for that view but I still see subview.

Comment: i suggest u set that view with a background, and check that its properly being resized with your code. i suspect its not the clipping but the resizing the one causing that issue

Comment: @Chiquis, so as you see I just set heigh to 0, so there is no height for constraint, but I still see subview. Do I need to resize frame?

Comment: Do the subviews have constraints applied? Do you see any warnings in the console when you do this?  As per @Chiquis, I would suggest removing all subviews and painting the view red, just to see that it's actually resizing properly. Often times setting the height constraint to 0 will produce warnings because other constraints will not allow it.

Comment: Setting the heigh to 0 could be nullified by other constrains, since the constrains handle a priority system and the interface will often break a constrain in order to satisfy others (even when its not what you want). As nebs suggested, paint it red, make sure you actually stop seeing the red when you resize, if you do not see the red, but still see the sub views then it is a clipping problem, but if you still see the red, then its a resizing problem